# Closed as not a real question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, close-reasons

This is the question: [Assemblies (Namespaces) used for retrieving XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762858/assemblies-namespaces-used-for-retrieving-xml-file/)

It was very poorly formatted and it wasn't clear what exactly was asked. When I saw it, it had already gotten many downvotes and I [have edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1837765).

The question was closed 6 minutes after my edit, but it was already readable and understandable. Does it mean that such questions, with many downvotes, are automatically closed?

*Updated:*

**Rachel** edited the question properly and now its reopened! I have reached my goal! =)

Comment: I admit that I'm not *that* familiar with C#, but I'm pretty sure that "assemblies" and "namespaces" are *not the same thing*. They usually relate to one another, but I don't believe that they have to. So you didn't really help the question. It is not "good to read and to understand". Indeed, the original formulation (without "assemblies" was probably *better*.

Comment: and why have you dovnvote my question?

Comment: Eleven people besides you viewed this question. Three of them downvoted it. Why do you think it was *me* instead of one of the other eight?

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. We are disagreeing the question has been improved enough to be reopened.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - thanks, I have read it. To dovnvote it here without any explanation doesnt answer this queston too.

Comment: A downvote (with or without an explanation) isn't supposed to answer the question anyway.

Comment: @Yannis - if someone disagree with my opinion - its ok. Wanted to have some explanation "why"

Comment: @MikroDel: remember, if **you** ask a question, then it will definitely be clear to you, because **you** know all the necessary background. Anyone who tries to answer it, however, will **only** see what you wrote and not what you thought (or considered "obvious").

Comment: You shouldn't be complaining about the downvotes here if you read the FAQ. If you _are_ complaining, you obviously _didn't_ read it.

Comment: @ColeJohnson where have you seen complains?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer - what have you comment to do with my question?

Comment: @MikroDel: you thought the question was just fine, others disagreed. Mike told you what exactly was missing. I was trying to tell you that you have to double- and tripple-check. Just because an answer you wrote is understandable to **you** doesn't mean that it's understandable to others as well.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - agreed

Comment: @JoachimSauer - find it much better to help someone - give an advice as a comment, trying to edit than to downvote and close.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - in this situation Rachel edited it properly and reopened the question. Its good =)

Comment: On commenting vs downvoting: welcome to stack exchange!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1837765) wasn't spectacular, the people who approved it should have ***im***proved it instead. I do believe the person who rejected it did so for the wrong reason though.

But just because you edited something it doesn't mean it will survive. I think there is enough information in it for someone to answer should they want to take the time, but it's not a brilliant question, hence the down votes. Note that I've edited in some extra code that the OP had posted as a comment, this wasn't posted till after your edit.

In addition to correcting the question, you could also use the comments to suggest improvements or additions - the user is new and clearly needed help.

Comment: I think its a big difference between great or brilliant question and question that have to be closed. Or have any questions on SO that are not great be closed?

Comment: @MikroDel It's a community decision to close it, it takes five ordinary users. I've added an edit to my answer which I hope explains a little more.

Answer (score 11):

> but it was already good to read and to understand

No, no it wasn't a good question. Why was it not a good question?

- `Assemblies (Namespaces) used for retrieving XML file?`

  - retrieving it from where? to do what?
- `Which Assemblies (Namespaces) should I use to access the XML file?`

  - access it to do what? (it's important to list a goal to help other understand what you're doing and thus help determine if you're approaching something incorrectly)
- `its showing error in Root.`

  - What is the exact error message?
  - Is the error seen while compiling, linking, or running the code?
- `i used System.Xml still its showing error`

  - How did you attempt to use it?
  - Is it the same error message as before or a different one?

The point here is detail is missing. You made some improvements on the post sure, but the raw details of what was desired should have been put in by the OP and without that it's a poor question at best.

> Does it mean that such a questions with many dovnvotes are close automatically?

No, it means users voted to close the question. Specifically users: `Mitch Wheat`, `sgar91`, `bash.d`, `user125697`, and `Soner Gönül`. If more/enough details is provided then it could be reopened, but as it stands I don't see a reason to do so.